# How do I sort a CSV file in a TTable?

Tags: delphi, sorting, csv

I have a TTable, and I am loading CSV files to this TTable. Three fields are there: Id, Hits & Path.
I made some lookup fields to this TTable with another query.

I want to sort the table. I am getting the message "Capability not supported." when I try to call `AddIndex('ndxHits','HITS',[]);`

Here is my code:

```
with DM.TblCVResults do
begin
  try
    Active     :=  False;
    TableName  :=  'C:\CSV\123.txt';
    Active     :=  True;

    AddIndex('ndxHits','HITS',[]);
    AddIndex('ndxCandidate','LkCandidate',[]);
    AddIndex('ndxLastCV','LkLastCV',[]);
    AddIndex('ndxPostCode','LkPostCode',[]);
    IndexDefs.Update;
    Active     :=  True;
    DM.TblCVResults.IndexName := 'ndxHits';
  except
    on E: Exception do
      MsgError(E.Message);
  end;
end
```

Comment: Did you write "Active := True;" before AddIndex?

Comment: I suggest you mark the answer to your previous question as an answer, that's what we do here

Comment: @Vijesh V. Nair: No you didn't, according to the code above. You set it Active *after* AddIndex and IndexDefs.Update.

Comment: @Ken, the issue is, Its not executing the Second" Active :=True." I Removed that and tried. Same Error

Comment: @Vijesh: It can only be opened once. The second does nothing. Does my answer below help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your previous question mentioned you were using `ttASCII` as the `TableType`. `ttASCII` tables, AFAIK, don't support indexes.

Your best bet is to load the `ttASCII TTable` content into a TClientDataset` (CDS), which does support indexes. I haven't tested with a ttASCII table as the source, but it should be as simple as:

Add a `TDatasetProvider` component to your application. Set it's `DataSet` property to your `TTable`.

Add a `TClientDataSet` component to your application. Set it's `ProviderName` to the `DataSetProvider` you added above. (I've named it CDS in the steps below.)

Open both the `Table` and the `ClientDataSet` (CDS), in that order.

```
Table1.Active := True;
CDS.Active := True;
```

Turn off updating of the `TTable` if you don't need it. (It's much faster.)

```
CDS.LogChanges := False;
```

Run the following code to create the indexes:

```
// Repeat for each additional index
with CDS.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do
begin
  Name := 'ndxHits';
  Fields := 'Hits';
  Options := [];
end;
```

Set the `ClientDataSet's` `IndexName` property to the index you want active:

```
CDS.IndexName := 'ndxHits';
```

Use the `ClientDataSet` like you would any other dataset. Search it using `Locate` or `FindKey`, add to it using `Insert` or `Append`, filter it, and so forth.

Comment: +1; BDE plain files (CSV and or fixed delimited) have very limited features, so fancy things (offered in indexed file based databases like Paradox and dBase, or server based databases) are not available. The +1 is for noting that, and describing the CDS alternative.

Comment: In the "IDXDesc (index descriptor)" topic of 'bde32.hlp' it is stated that indexing is not supported with the text driver.

Comment: 1 more Question, I want the Descending Sort; How I can do with CDS.Indexname ?

Comment: with CDS.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do
  begin
    Name := 'ndxHits';
    Fields := 'Hits';
    DescFields:='HITS';
    Options := [];
  end;

Comment: @Vijesh V. Nair: A quick check of the help file for TIndexDef.Options shows TIndexOptions, which includes ixDescending. So it would be 'Options := [ixDescending];'. See the help file for other values for Options.

Comment: YOu are Rignt. I am facing an issue time consuming. Lemme explain my problem. I have One ID and 2 Other Fields in a CsV file. the ID connected to a database table. I have to show the curresponding entries in the db and fields from Csv. Need sort the Datset too. My Idea was load into a ClientDataset, lookup to a Query with table and Use sort and show. My Csv have 85 K Records and its taking 120 seconds to load and sort. Can you tell me, can I use Bacthmove for this. So I can easily pick filds by a simple query.